# Where should API Request Model to Database model conversion happen when controllers and logic are in separate projects

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a small ASP.NET API that exists in two separate projects.  The API project holds my controller classes and request/response models.  The Logic project holds business logic and database models.

If a user submits a request, lets say a BookRequest, to my endpoint, where is the best location to handle conversion to my Book database model?  Originally I had planned to have the Book model take a BookRequest as a constructor, however that would create a cyclical dependency, as Logic would need to reference API.  I could move the RequestModels into the Logic project, however I feel those should live in the API project as they are specific to the controllers.  The alternative would then be to have the API convert to the database model and pass that to the logic.

Is there a better method for handling this case while keeping the projects seperate?

Comment: For me, the thing that's responsible for working with and returning a certain object should be responsible for any conversion to that object. So if you have a service that returns a book model, that calls a repo that returns a book entity, it should be the service that does the conversion as it's the one that needs it in that form. If the repo did it, it's now been coupled to the service to some degree as it now needs to know what to convert to so the service can use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the cyclical dependency you described you may want to consider breaking things out into a third project, with its own models. The problem comes in because your 'Logic' project maintains both your business logic and database models.

A simple example would be:

**API** *with API-Models* <--> **Business Logic** *with DTOs* <--> **DAL** *with DB Models / Entities*

In this example the Business Logic layer would handle the translation of API Models to DTOs (Data Transfer Objects), and DTOs to values returned from the DAL (Data Access Layer).

Consider researching common architecture patterns to find one that may fit your needs. A common pattern I often use is the Clean Architecture.

Here is a link to Microsoft Architecture Patterns documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/modern-web-apps-azure/common-web-application-architectures

Comment: In your example, would the DTO project still have to reference the API if its handling the translation?  Or would I opt for the controller class in the API creating a new DTO object something like: `PostBook(BookModel book){ ...
new BookDTO(book.name, book.author);
...`

Comment: It depends on what works best in your specific case. Its hard to say without having a larger view of your overall architecture. Give a few different architecure patterns a try. There are lots of tutorials out there - the best way to find what works for you is to try several and throw away those that don't work. However, in the example I gave the DTO project would reference both the API and DAL.